# Why does my interger take two tries to properly subtract?

Tags: java, netbeans, int, subtraction

I am a beginning Java programmer coding a mini game similar to the game Minecraft except the graphics will be lightweight and the theme of the game medieval. I am currently working on tool durability and score/experience calculations. But I am having trouble with the tool durability. The durability of the pickaxe is 100, or int pickaxe = 100. In the game, you can mine 10 resources or 50 resources. No matter what one you try, the first time you mine it the durability will stay at 100 and the resources will be added to the starter resources, or int resources = 150.    Yet any other time you mine resources, it will properly subtract. The adding of the resources works perfect, its just the durability that is off. This is very unusual to me. If it helps I am using Java JDK 1.8.0_05 on Windows 7 Home Premium with 4 GB of ram and 1 TB of space and I am using the Netbeans IDE 8.0.1 to develop this program. Thank you for taking the time to read this question.

---

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try{
        AudioInputStream audioInputStream =AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(this.getClass().getResource("select.wav"));

        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audioInputStream);
        clip.start( );
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {}       

    resources = resources + 10;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your remaining pickaxe use is:");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, pickaxe);
    score = score + 50;

    pickaxe = pickaxe - 10;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your resource balace");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, resources);

    if (pickaxe < 0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You need more pickaxe use! Adding More for 15 Resources!");
        resources = resources - 15;
        pickaxe = 100;
    }
}
```

Comment: How about showing us the code in question?

Comment: You need to post the segments of code that are giving you an issue. We cannot help you by reading that :)

Comment: Ok, I will paste the code shortly.

Comment: The code is posted. I'm sorry if its a little too long, but its the whole process considering it has to play an audio tone to represent clicking buttons.

Comment: You are subtracting only *after* you display the pickaxe use.

Comment: So I need to subtract it first. Ah.... stupid me. I understand. Thanks for the help guys. I tested the code and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You issue is quite simple, you are doing the said subtraction after you are displaying your Pickaxes usage:

---

```
    resources = resources + 10;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your remaining pickaxe use is:");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, pickaxe);
    score = score + 50;
```

This needs to happen before displaying:

```
    pickaxe = pickaxe - 10;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your resource balace");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, resources);
```

---

Hope this helps.